# Do Intents supersede permissions when it comes access?

Tags: android, permissions, android-intent, launch

I am trying to submit an app, and when I spot the .apk it tells me this:

This apk requests 0 permissions that users will be warned about

but, in the Manifest, I made a note to include:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is this simply because I launch my camera in an Intent, rather than a contentView, etc...?  Or is this a problem I need to look into before I submit?

THanks

Edit  --

The app works on my phone when I remove them, so maybe they aren't needed?  I was told a while back that launching the camera with an intent did not require a permission in the manifest, but I wanted to double check.  I feel like the permission tags are correct, and I placed them in different parts of the manifest, and deleted them, but the app still ran - is it an issue I don't need to worry about then?

Comment: Are you sure you have the uses-permission at the right place in the manifest?

Comment: do they need to be in a specific place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are able to actually do these things (that your permissions tags are working)  It may be that they are "normal" rather than "dangerous" permissions so they don't show up as prominent warnings during installation unless you click the thing at the bottom to see all used permissions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Edit:

At least on my phone though, using the camera does show up on the first warnings screen.

Do the functions you requested the permissions to enable actually work?  If they are working, what happens if you take the corresponding permissions out of the manifest (ie, if they still work, this would indicate that you didn't put them in the right place, and that you don't need them because your intent is causing the work to be done by some other application which already has permission and does not check a permission on the intent sender)

Comment: Let's put it this way: if you remove them and the app keeps working then know that you didn't need them, and quite possibly that you also did them wrong which is why they aren't displaying as warnings.   But if removing them breaks the app, then you know you did need them and you did them right, but they aren't important enough to trigger user warnings.  Finally, if the app doesn't work with them where they are, you know you do need them and you did them wrong (or you have other problems)